# How to judge the convergence of $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}{x} d x$

Tags: calculus

How to judge the convergence of $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x}{x} d x$。I know the Abel method and Dirichlet method, but neither works for the problem. I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $\frac{\pi}{2} - \text{arctan}(x) = \text{arctan}(\frac{1}{x})$. Now substitute $x = \frac{1}{u}$ to convert the integral to 
$$ \int_0 ^1 \frac{\arctan(u)}{u} \text{d}u$$
which is seen to converge, because it's continuous at $0$.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you! It is clear enough!